# Sort array of arrays that is a value of a hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash

I saw several posts on sorting an array that is a value of a hash, but I'm trying to sort an array of arrays that is a value of a hash.
I have a hash that looks like this:

```
h = { 
      "pets"=>[["dog", 1], ["cat", 2]],
      "fruits"=>[["orange", 1], ["apple", 2]]
     }
```

I would like to sort array of arrays according to the first elements (string) of the arrays inside.
So I want the result to be

```
{ 
  "pets"=>[["cat", 2], ["dog", 1]],
  "fruits"=>[["apple", 2], ["orange", 1]]
}
```

This is what I have right now:

```
h.map do |key, value|
  value.sort_by! { |x, y| x[0] <=> y[0] }
end
```

But this just returns the original array. What do I need to change?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one issue I see is that you are attempting to `map` your hash. That will always return an array.

In this case, you’ll get back something like this:
`[[["cat", 2], ["dog", 1]], [["apple", 2], ["orange", 1]]]`

If you want to modify your hash in place, you can do:

```
h.each { |key, value| h[key] = value.sort_by { ... } }
```

Then `h` will be the new hash, sorted as you expect.
Or you can set it to another variable:

```
new_hash = h.each { |key, value| value.sort_by! { ... } }
```

Next, it looks like you’ve confused `sort` and `sort_by`. (Easy to do) 
When you use `sort`, the two variables you pass in your block are assigned to the values being compared. (In your case, the arrays `["dog", 1]` is one argument, and the other would be another array to compare it to, like `["cat", 2]`)
However, `sort_by` expects you to do the computing to determine where it’s place is in the new order. Normally `sort_by` only accepts a single argument, but because you’re working with arrays (and because of the way Ruby handles tuples) when you tell `sort_by` to accept 2 arguments (`x` and `y`) those are set to the first and second values of your array. (`x == "dog"`, `y == 1`)

So you’ve got 2 options here: Keep your block the same and switch your enumerable method to `sort`, or switch to `sort_by` and change your block:

`sort`:

```
h.each { |key, value| h[key] = value.sort! { |x, y| x[0] <=> y[0] } }
```

`sort_by`:

```
h.each { |key, value| h[key] = value.sort_by! { |x, y| y } } # In this case, `y` is the second value in your arrays, which is the integer
```

Comment: Just call `to_h` on the array returned by `Hash#map` to get the hash back.

Answer (score 3):

```
h.merge(h) { |*, n| n.sort }
  #=> {"pets"=>[["cat", 2], ["dog", 1]], "fruits"=>[["apple", 2], ["orange", 1]]}
```

This does not modify `h`.

This uses the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged, which here is all keys. The block has three block variables, the common key `k`, the value of `k` for the "old hash, `o` and the value of `k` for the "new" hash, `n`. (Here `o` and `n` are of course equal.) I'm only using the last of these variables, so I've expressed the block variables as `|*, n|`, rather than `|k, o, n|`. See the doc for details.

Another way that does not mutate `h`:

```
h.each_key.zip(h.each_value.map(&:sort)).to_h
  #=> {"pets"=>[["cat", 2], ["dog", 1]], "fruits"=>[["apple", 2], ["orange", 1]]}
```

This could instead be written

```
h.keys.zip(h.values.map(&:sort)).to_h
```

Comment: Outstanding `merge` usage, Cary. Thanks, I really enjoyed seeing this. In the latter example `h[k].sort!` should be enough.

Comment: minor nitpick, there's `each_key` you can use instead of `keys.each`, probably just a style preference, but it's a thing, there's also `each_value` since you're sorting in place

Comment: Good point, @SimpleLime, but I decided to remove that line and stick with solutions that do not mutate the hash. In my replacement I see I could use `each_key` with `Enumerable#zip`.

Answer (score 3):

Immutable version, having no side effects:

```
h.map { |k, v| [k, v.sort_by(&:first)] }.to_h
```